# Convert String "MM/dd/yy" in to date MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am try to convert string 11/08/91(MM/dd/yy) into 11/08/1991(MM/dd/yyyy) but it is give wrong output link 
**Date is :0091-11-07 18:06:32 +0000**

- My original output is 11/08/1991

My Code

```
NSString *strdate = @"11/08/91";

NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateformate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateformate dateFromString:strdate];

NSLog(@"Date is :%@",date);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this it will give right date,

```
  NSString *strdate = @"11/08/91";

NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateformate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];

NSDate *date = [dateformate dateFromString:strdate];


NSLog(@"Date is :%@",date);
```

It will give `1991-11-07 18:30:00 +0000`

Then you can do like,

```
  [dateformate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSString *str = [dateformate stringFromDate:date];
NSDate *finalDate = [dateformate dateFromString:str];
```

and it will give,

`final date str is 11/08/1991`

`final date is 1991-11-07 18:30:00 +0000`

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *strdate = @"11/08/91";

NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateformate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];

NSDate *date = [dateformate dateFromString:strdate];

[dateformate setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
//date = [dateformate dateFromString:[dateformate stringFromDate:date] ];
NSLog(@"Date is :%@",[dateformate stringFromDate:date]);
```

Output is :  Date is :11/08/1991